# Entity Framework join query with int array

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have got 3 tables on my database.

**---Student---**

*id - name*

**---Language---**

*id - lang*

---StudentLanguage---(**Common Table**)

*id - studentId - langId*

Students can have more languages. i want to search students with an `int[]` array values. But not with `IN()` - `Contains()`, it must be with `and` - `&&` operator and this operator take `int[]` values.

in sql =

```
`select t1.id, t1.name from Student t1 join StudentLanguage t2 
ON(t1.id=t2.studentId) where (t2.langId=1 and t2.langId=3 and t2.langId=5);`
```

so how can i do this query with Entity Framework? (...`where new int[] { 1,3,5 }`)

Comment: All I can think of is looping through your array and doing a seperate query inside each loop iteration. Then you can meld the results together into one result set

Comment: @rory but OP wants solution in linqToSQL i gess

Comment: @teovankot answer with pseudo code given

Comment: I don't think EF can translate any linq into that sql. You will need to provide your own implementation for that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

This code generate some clumsy sql query...

```
        int[] ids = new[] { 1, 3, 5 };
        var acc = from st in db.Students select st;

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            int id1 = id;
            var res =
                from st in db.Students
                from lng in st.Language
                where lng.Id == id1
                select st;
            acc =
                from a in acc
                join st in res on a.Id equals st.Id
                select a;
        }

        acc.ToList();
```

... sql query :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM    [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudentLanguage] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Student_Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudentLanguage] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[Student_Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudentLanguage] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[Student_Id]
WHERE ([Extent2].[Language_Id] = @p__linq__0) 
       AND ([Extent3].[Language_Id] = @p__linq__1) 
       AND ([Extent4].[Language_Id] = @p__linq__2)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<int> langIds = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 }.ToList();
var c = langIds.Count;
var res2 = _context.Students
   .Where(x => x.StudentLanguages
      .Where(l => langIds.Contains(l.langId)).Select(y => y.langId).Distinct().Count() >= c);
```

result SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[name]
FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [t0]
WHERE ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[langId]
        FROM [dbo].[StudentLanguage] AS [t1]
        WHERE ([t1].[langId] IN (1, 3, 5)) AND ([t1].[studentId] = [t0].[id])
        ) AS [t2]
    )) >= 3
```

Use `Distinct` if `StudentLanguages` theoretically may have several overlapping bundles `StudentId` - `LangId`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
resultArr = [];

For(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var result = db.Student.Where(s=>s.StudentLanguage.langId == arr[i]);
    resultArr.append(result);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you wrute it in C#?

Comment: @teovankot - pseudo C#. We don't spoonfeed around these here parts ;-)

Comment: @rory thanks but where is join statement in your entitiy framework linq query ? there is a common table for that.

Comment: @ASPMaker - you don't need join statements in EF linq query's. The linking is in the `Student.StudentLanguage` part through navigation properties

Comment: @rory we can do this with framework api. But i want to learn with join statement.

Comment: @ASPMaker - I don't know if that's possible. If you are using EF, why do you want to use joins?

Comment: @rory entity framework has got join statement and i want to learn many to many with common table and join .

Answer (score 0):

I try to search how to do it and here is what i come out with:

```
int[] langIds = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };
var lang = _context.Languages.Where(x => langIds.Contains(x.id));
var result = _context.Students.Where(x => !lang
                                   .Except(x.StudentLanguages
                                       .Select(y => y.Language)
                                   .Intersect(lang)).Any());
```

Here i use `Except` and `Intersect` **linqToSQL** extension methods.

It produces this SQL statement:

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[name]
FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[id], [t1].[name]
        FROM [dbo].[Language] AS [t1]
        WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT [t3].[id], [t3].[name]
                FROM [dbo].[StudentLanguage] AS [t2]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Language] AS [t3] ON [t3].[id] = [t2].[langId]
                WHERE (EXISTS(
                    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                    FROM [dbo].[Language] AS [t4]
                    WHERE ([t3].[id] = [t4].[id]) AND ([t4].[id] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2))
                    )) AND ([t2].[studentId] = [t0].[id])
                ) AS [t5]
            WHERE [t1].[id] = [t5].[id]
            ))) AND ([t1].[id] IN (@p3, @p4, @p5))
        ) AS [t6]
))
```

Note that i populate languages from database. Unfortunatly **you can not use local collections in your query** since LinqToSQL don't know how to translate them into SQL. If you do the same thing with local int array or any other collection you will get this exception:

> LINQ To SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL
>   implementation of query operators except the Contains operator

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
var langIds = new[] { 1, 3, 5 };

IEnumerable<Student> student = from st in db.student select st;

foreach (var item in langIds)
{
  student = student.Join(db.StudentLanguage.Where(w => w.langId == item),
  st => st.studentId,
  stMap => stMap.id,
  (st, stMap) => new { Student= stMap, StudentLanguage = st})
  .Select(x => x.Student).Distinct();
}
```

i can do this like that. Maybe `foreach` can be turn linq and this code can be only one line and a little short.

Comment: Your query have an error in last string. You selecting Anonymouse type.

Comment: @teo van kot but it returns true result for me.